# How do I allow a ping to a user in selinux?

Tags: selinux

linux: RedHat  8.5
For example, a postgres user is taken.

```
sudo su postgres ping 8.8.8.8
bash: ping: Permission denied
```

If disable selinux on host, then everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Run your command like this: `sudo -u postgres ping 8.8.8.8`

```
# sudo -u postgres ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=5.51 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=4.46 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=5.43 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.463/5.136/5.512/0.476 ms
#
```